# Excel VBA Create a list and add only unique terms

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to pull strings from column A and move them to column B only if they don't already exist in column B. To do this, I wanted to make a list and scan all of column A with it, however, I'm not sure how to do that in VBA. In python I recall using something along the lines of

```
[If (x) not in (List)]
```

but that same approach isnt working for me in Excel.

Currently, I have the following

```
Sub GatherAll()

GL = List()
rwcnt = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
lastc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To rwcnt
    Cells(i, 1).Value = n
```

and I want to say something like

```
if n not in GL, GL.append(n)
continue
```

`End Sub`

If anyone could help me out, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Does column B already have some values?

Comment: Would copy-pasting all of Column A, then using Excel's Remove Duplicates feature work just as well?

Comment: It does not, column B is empty and honestly the list of unique strings can be placed anywhere, I just chose B cause it wasn't A.

Comment: MatthewD's question is important. Do you want to create a new list in column B every time you launch the macro, or add to the existing list? (Which may have values not present in A at all).

Comment: every time I launch the macro I would like a new list in the column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adapting the following code to your exact needs and see if it helps. If you need help, let us know.

```
Sub MoveUniqueEntries()
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim rToMove As Range
    Dim rDest As Range
    Dim rLoop As Range

    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set rToMove = Intersect(Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, Sheet1.Columns(1))
    Set rDest = Sheet1.Range("B1")

    For Each rLoop In rToMove
        If oDict.exists(rLoop.Value) Then
            'Do nothing
        Else
            oDict.Add rLoop.Value, 0
            rDest.Value = rLoop.Value
            Set rDest = rDest.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next rLoop
End Sub
```

Comment: If you choose this method, note that you must first enable reference to the Microsoft Scipting Runtime by going (in the VBE) in Tools > References > Check "Microsoft Scipting Runtime". This makes it possible for the file to use dictionnaries (whether it is being used on your computer, or a collegue's computer, doesn't matter).

Comment: @DavidGM It is my understanding that a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime is not necessary since we've used late binding (`CreateObject`). If we choose to use early binding (`Dim oDict as New Scripting.Dictionary`), then we'd need to create the reference

Comment: Maybe you are right, I never did it your way. I didn't think it was unnecessary when late binding! @ScottT Did you have to do what I wrote?

Comment: @DavidGM Thanks for mentioning it though. Reference issues potentially throw errors that are always annoying to diagnose. I checked my References, and I don't have the Scripting Runtime selected, yet I use Dictionaries all the time.

Comment: I already had Microsoft Scripting Runtime activated, so I don't know if it was necessary or not, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

In your VBA IDE you will have to add a reference.  On the tools pulldown menu select references. Then select "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library".

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
    'Add fields to your recordset for storing data.  You can store sums here.
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "Row", adInteger
        .Fields.Append "Value", adInteger
        .Open
    End With

    lRow = 1

    'Loop through and record what is in the first column
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

        rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields("Row").Value = lRow
        rs.Fields("Value").Value = ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value
        rs.Update

        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop

    'Now go through and list out the unique values in columnB.
    lRow = 1
    rs.Sort = "value"
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count
        if rs.Fields("value").Value <> strLast then

            ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value = rs.Fields("value").Value

            lRow = lRow + 1
        End if
        strLast = rs.Fields("value").Value
    Loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the aid again, I'll definitely look back at this in the future :D

Comment: Sure thing.  Reading data into a recordset is a very flexible way to do things.  You can filter and sort the recordset as well as access it for any need.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-platform version (but will be slow for large numbers of values):

```
Sub UniquesTester()

    Dim v, u(), i As Long, n As Long
    n = 0
    v = Range(Range("A1"), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
    ReDim u(1 To UBound(v, 1))
    For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        If IsError(Application.Match(v(i, 1), u, 0)) Then
            n = n + 1
            u(n) = v(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve u(1 To n)

    Range("c1").Resize(n, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(u)

End Sub
```